# How to add form to email with redirect?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a website and I want to add a form to email with PHP, but I am not very good with it. How do I solve this problem?

#### Attempt

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Checkout</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">

 
 
 
 
 </head>
<body>
    <header>
            <div class="container">
                    <h1 class="logo">LOLLYSHOP</h1>
      
                      <nav>
                         <ul>
                             <img src="file:///C:/Users/zam/Downloads/lines-menu.svg" alt="" width="40" height="40">
                          </ul>
                      </nav>  
                  </div>
    </header>
    <div>
        <img id="badla" src="https://sc01.alicdn.com/kf/UTB8lgV0pWrFXKJk43Ovq6ybnpXay/latest-shirt-design-for-men.jpg" height="250" width="250">
        <p id="suit">Blue Suit</p>
        <p id="suit">Price<strong>:</strong>$50</p>
        
  
  <form action="https://formspree.io/aliabououf@gmail.com" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
 
  
        <input type="hidden" name="itemid" value="1"> 
        <h2>Name:          <input type="username" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" name="username" required></h2>
        <h2>Address:</h2>
        <textarea placeholder="Type Your Address" rows="20" id="comment_text" cols="40" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" name="address" required></textarea>
      <br> <br>
      <p id="note"><b>Note:Payement is When Recieving</b></p>      
        <a href="done.html"><button type="submit" value="Buy" id="buy1">Buy</button></a>
    </form> 
 
 <?php

 if(!isset($_POST['submit'])) 
 {
// the message
$Item = $_POST['itemid'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$address = $_POST['comment_text'];


mail("aliabououf@gmail.com","E-Market","Item : " $Item "Name :" $name "address:" $address );
header('Location: done.html')
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use services like `formspree`. What you should do instead is using a ready-made PHP-Mailer class like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).
You could (theoretically) use the `mail()` class but this is not a good idea. Why you don't want to use the `mail()` function is explained on their GitHub page:

> The only PHP function that supports this is the mail() function. However, it does not provide any assistance for making use of popular features such as HTML-based emails and attachments.
>
> Formatting email correctly is surprisingly difficult. There are myriad overlapping RFCs, requiring tight adherence to horribly complicated formatting and encoding rules - the vast majority of code that you'll find online that uses the mail() function directly is just plain wrong! Please don't be tempted to do it yourself - if you don't use PHPMailer, there are many other excellent libraries that you should look at before rolling your own - try SwiftMailer, Zend/Mail, eZcomponents etc.
>
> The PHP mail() function usually sends via a local mail server, typically fronted by a sendmail binary on Linux, BSD and OS X platforms, however, Windows usually doesn't include a local mail server; PHPMailer's integrated SMTP implementation allows email sending on Windows platforms without a local mail server.

PHPMailer allows a simple integration and configuration and can be easily installed and implemented.
There are a ton of good tutorials about PHPMailer on the internet. A basic example is already provided on their GitHub page:

```
<?php
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

// Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                       // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'user@example.com';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'secret';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                                  // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    // Attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

If this is above your current skill level you have to take a look at PHP basics. Knowledge about namespaces for example are essential. For beginners the `mail()` function or services like `formspree` look fairly easy but I recommend you to do it right or to not do it at all.